# Does @Rnderbody() mvc 4 reloads the total page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Does Renderbody reloads the total page when a view is called in to layout? If so how to call a view without reloading the total page??

Comment: No, RenderBody doesn't reload the page, but it only ever runs when the page is first loaded because it is *server-side code*. If you want to update parts of the page without a full reload, you need AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into `partial views` and `ajax` to update without reloading the whole page.

[Partial view tutorial](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html)

[Questions tagged here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial-views)